# VueJS independent components events

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that emit event through a bus as indicated below. The same component need to be included twice on another component. I want the events emitted to populate different variables;

```
    //component.vue
    <template>
        <div>
            Hello there?
            <a @click="changed">New</a>

            <ol>
               <li v-for="option in list">
                   <div class='row justify-content-start'>
                      <div class='col-sm-6'><input v-model="option.value" type='text' placeholder="key"/></div>
                      <div class='col-sm-6'><input v-model="option.name" type='text' placeholder="Name"/></div>
                   </div>
               </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      export default{
            props:['options','iscolumn'],
            data(){
                  return {list:this.options,item:{name:'',value:''}}
            },
            methods:{
                  changed(){
                        $bus.$emit('add-option',this.item,this.iscolumn);
                  }
            }
      }
    </script>
/** root.vue **/

<template>
      <div>
            <h3>Rows</h3>
            <div><rows :options="rows" :iscolumn="false"/></div>


            <h3>Columns</h3>
            <div><rows :options="columns" :iscolumn="true" /></div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
      export default{
            components:{'rows':require('./component')},
            data(){
                  return {
                        columns:[],rows:[]
                  }
            },
            created(){
                  this.$bus.$on('add-option',(option,iscolumn)=>{
                        if (is_column) {this.columns.push(option);}
                        else this.rows.push(option);
                  })
            }
      }
</script>
```

When I click on the ***New*** from root both columns and rows get populated.
Looking for case where each of the component are independent, can't understand how they are sharing variables.
Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: share any live demo or snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign unique key attributes to the `rows` components:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Rows</h3>
        <div><rows key="rows1" :options="rows" :iscolumn="false"/></div>

        <h3>Columns</h3>
        <div><rows key="rows2" :options="columns" :iscolumn="true" /></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter. Will test and get back.